# Android - Swap SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, supportmapfragment

I have two xml files (Android layouts) for my Tablet app that, where I want to swap a custom MapFragment with another Fragment if the layout is one-pane layout.

Here is the layout I'm using to start my view with a list of locations (inital fragment is a ListFragment and works fine) and so in middle_frame.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/header_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Next here is my map_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_fragment_framelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

When I click on a list item in the ListFragment, I want to update the map so it moves to new a location, so I replace "header_frame" but it gives me a null-pointer exception. This is because of the MapFragment class not being in the single-pane layout. How can I swap them out? I tried calling 
setContentView(R.layout.map_layout.xml) but this throws the same error. How can I setup the layouts properly?